# Visual Studio freeglut/glew error ("missing from computer")

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, glew, freeglut

Long story short:
I'm at home trying to run a project I've been tinkering with in school (OpenGL).
When trying to run the unchanged program, I get errors saying freeglut.dll is missing.
The thing is:

- I have freeglut and glew on my computer
- I am running the same version of Visual Studio (2013)
- The path to the libraries and such is *exactly* the same due to the glew and freeglut-files being located in a Dropbox-folder on both PCs.
- The .dlls are also located in the same folders as the .exe

I have tried rebuilding, cleaning, starting a new project with the same files, moving the freeglut and glew-files to different folders, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on both machines? I bet `freeglut.dll` depends on an external DLL that is only present on one of them.

Comment: Yeah, seem to have found a few of those using Dependency Walker.
I also realized that VS is Ultimate 2013 on the PC it doesn't work on and Professional 2013 with update 4.
Should I install Professional 2013 with update 4 on the non-working PC or should I try to tinker with .dlls?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rebooting your system?

Comment: Sounds like Dell support. Care to explain why it would help?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Turns out I had Visual Studio Ultimate on the non-working PC and not Visual Studio Professional. Installing Professional did the trick.